# Grid - Not able to run the multiple instance When we set both 'RemoteWebDriver' and 'WebDriver' as static. it returns null value

Tags: selenium-grid

```
When we call this Driver() method in Another class ex: 'main.TestNG.Driver()'. This 'Driver()' method is calling 'getDriver()' method
and getDriver() method is returns null value insteads of remote value. due to this issue i can't access those webdriver in another class.

We are using Keyword driven approach, we want to run this multiple script using grid approach in multiple nodes (instance) 
When we set both 'RemoteWebDriver' and 'WebDriver' as static only 1 instance is execute
```

How to resolve the null ?

```
package main;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Parameters;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import Utility.AppProperties;
import Utility.ExecLogger;

public class TestNG extends AppProperties{
public ThreadLocal<RemoteWebDriver> threadDriver = new ThreadLocal<RemoteWebDriver>();
public WebDriver driver;

@Parameters({"browser"})
@BeforeClass
public void setup(String browser) throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException {

    DesiredCapabilities capability=new DesiredCapabilities();

      if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("firefox")){
       System.out.println("firefox");
       capability= DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
       capability.setBrowserName("firefox"); 
       capability.setPlatform(org.openqa.selenium.Platform.ANY);
      }
      if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("iexplore")){
      System.setProperty("webdriver.iexplore.driver", "..........\\iexplore.exe");
       System.out.println("iexplore");
       capability= DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
       capability.setBrowserName("iexplore"); 
       capability.setPlatform(org.openqa.selenium.Platform.WINDOWS);
      }
      if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("Chrome")){
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "..........\\chromedriver.exe");
            ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
            chromeOptions.addArguments(Arrays.asList("--test-type"));
            capability = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
            capability.setBrowserName("chrome");
            capability.setCapability("chrome.switches", Arrays.asList("--incognito"));
            capability.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, chromeOptions);
          }`enter code here`
      threadDriver.set(new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"),capability));
     Driver();
}

public RemoteWebDriver getDriver() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
              return threadDriver.get();
}

public WebDriver Driver(){
             try {
                    loadProperties();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block`
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                 driver = getDriver();
                  driver.get(getUrl());
                  driver.manage().window().maximize();
            return driver;
        }
}
```

When we call this Driver() method in Another class ex: 'main.TestNG.Driver()'. This 'Driver()' method is calling 'getDriver()' method
    and getDriver() method is returns null value insteads of remote value. due to this issue i can't access those webdriver in another class.

```
We are using Keyword driven approach, we want to run this multiple script using grid approach in multiple nodes (instance) 
When we set both 'RemoteWebDriver' and 'WebDriver' as static only 1 instance is execute
```

How to resolve the null ?

Comment: Please add the entire stacktrace.

Comment: How are you making sure @BeforeClass is executing?

Comment: - Niharika_neo      
                               @BeforeClass is calling when we call the class, this class automatically initiate. But if we call the 'Driver()' in another class it's not calling the required  Threaddriver() method
 
                 If I set both 'RemoteWebDriver' and 'WebDriver' as static, 2 browser windows are opened and the first few steps of the test scripts (login into the webpage) works fine. But after that the scripts start behaving weirdly. The second script continues execution but does not perform all actions and the first script stops right after login.